# Lyx: The number of items in reference are missing

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, templates

New to the latex. Recently I use the template download from [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dtyeh/thesistemplate.html) ('Lyx Thesis Template for Stanford University') .
In the reference, before the items, there is no index. See the output of this template, in the Bibliography it shows:

M. Abe and J. O. Smith III. Design...

But what we want is:

[1] M. Abe and J. O. Smith III. Design...

How can I recover it? Also in the citation, we want it to show something like "(1)", not "(Abe and Smith III, 2004)" (see the "Introduction" of the output). (I am not sure if this is another question or the same one.)

(yesterday I ask the same question. But because of some problems happen to my account, I need to post it again.)

Comment: Ever checked the options in LyX>Document>Settings>Bibliography? Look for Author-Year vs Numeric.

Comment: That is not working.

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography

Comment: @hengyue That's because of the `\bibpunct` command in the preamble; just remove it.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason exactly. @PhilipPirrip Great! But I have no way to adopt your answer.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Could you write up a proper answer?

Comment: @hengyue Can you please amend your question, saying what kind of template this is (Stanford, ported to LyX) and where the original LaTeX template can be downloaded from. Then I'll write up my answer.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip  the link is redirected to the page where one can download the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch from Author-Year

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

to Numbers

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

go to LyX>Document>Settings>Bibliography and choose the appropriate Style Variant.

Then in LyX>Document>Settings>LaTeX Preamble comment out the line

```
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
```

which seems to make the natbib package use Author-Year style again, to read

```
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
```